# How to rotate kms encryption key for Client-Side Field Level Encryption in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, encryption

We are currently using Client-Side Field Encryption in mongo. We have a requirement to rotate the encryption keys every year. But the documentation only provides ways of rotating using the general mongo encryption and not the encryption done with client side.

Is there a way to rotate the keys for that kind of encryption? Or will we have to manually decrypt and reencrypt the data by having the old and newly rotated keys?

Comment: Usually you rotate the application key, the data encryption key remains the same - see how KMS works: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/csfle/reference/kms-providers/#std-label-csfle-reference-kms-providers, or a serviceless implementations like in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-seal.php. If your requirement is to rotate the actual data encryption key, then yes, you will need to update all affected documents one by one.

Comment: @AlexBlex Do you know what the standard requirements are? Is it usually just the key encryption key that is rotated and not the key itself?

Comment: Sorry, there is no one-size-fits-all requirements. If you just care about privacy - use the KMS and rotate the keys as often as you can afford. It will help to detect/prevent use of the keys stored on compromised application servers.  Annual rotation spells data loss is not business critical, so you should be good. If requirements come from regulations/certifications - you have to follow them literally, they define standards that you should comply with.  The may or may not require full data re-encryption.

Comment: Ok thank you. The client is very vague in their requirements, so we are trying to do what needs to be done to ensure proper security while trying to avoid excessive downtime for reencryption. Seems as you said there's no straight-forward answer and we'll see with the client. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, to rotate the data key:  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/reference/method/KeyVault.rewrapManyDataKey/